# MS Edge Remote Debugging Inspect can't connect to Windows remote device

Tags: microsoft-edge, remote-debugging

I am trying to debug a tab on Edge(83) on another PC running on the local network, both debuggee and debugger are Windows 10 and Edge(83).

I followed all the instructions from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/devtools-guide-chromium/remote-debugging/windows

When I go to edge://inspect/#devices on my local and enter the ip+port of the remote pc and click connect it says "can't connect to device at that address".

If I take the same ip+port and enter into a tab on Edge it instantly open the device portal page of the remote pc.

So its clear Device Portal is enabled and running and that I can connect from the debugger pc to debugee pc.

So why wont edge://inspect connect?

I have double and triple checked the obvious things, Edge Remote Tool installed on the remote pc, remote debugging enabled on local pc, debug through portal enabled on remote pc, I have even tried edge://inspect on the remote pc and even there it won't connect.

Must be missing something, any ideas?
TIA Rob

Comment: Have you set the Debuggee PC Network to private, through Settings > Network & Internet > Wi-Fi, click on your network and toggle the Network profile button to Private?

Comment: Yes both pc's have network marked private

Answer (score 0):

in edge://inspect/#devices
F12 show

> Uncaught ReferenceError: enableRemoteWindowsDevices is not defined

input

```
$('#remote-windows-device-settings').hidden = false;
$('#device-portal-credentials').hidden=false;
```